As of October 2024, have any statements been made by Trump or Musk that the latter may have a formal role in the former's government if elected?
I've noticed murmurs of an idea Elon Musk play some role in Government should Trump be elected in 2024, including memes alluding to potential involvement:

and Musk appearing at a Trump rally:

Question
Have any statements (formal or otherwise) been made by either Trump (or his campaign) or Musk about whether Musk may have some role in Government should Trump be elected president of the USA in 2024?
Note: I couldn't spot anything in the most obvious place, Trump's website.

Trump has said he would not make Musk a cabinet official, but would likely make him an "efficiency czar" of some sort (where czar is just a fancy term for a presidential advisor).

“He wants to be involved. Now, look, he’s running big businesses and all that, so, he can’t really — I don’t think he’d be [free] for the Cabinet,” Trump said in an interview on the “Shawn Ryan Show.”
“I’d put him in the Cabinet, absolutely, but I don’t know how he could do that with all the things he’s got going,” he continued. “But he could sort of, as the expression goes, consult with the country and give you some very good ideas.”

